# Why is my nav-icon "hamburger" icon suddenly invisible yet still works?

Tags: javascript, nav

I have a site written for me a long time ago.  All of a sudden the "hamburger icon" stopped appearing. It's still there, as I can click on it and the drop down menu appears.

I have zero experience with Javascript and am tied up on trying to learn Swift.

Any chance that something is wrong with the outside referenced script? I am able to change the nav bar from light to dark. But can't seem to figure out why this icon just disappeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title>My Site</title>

    <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    

    <style type="text/css">

  body {

    padding-top: 0px;

  }



  .container {

    width: 550px;

  }

  

</style>

  </head>

  <body>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

<!--

if (screen.width <= 699) {

document.location = "mobile/index.html";


}

//-->

</script>



<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p style="font-size:150%;margin:20px;width:50%;padding-top:25px">

</p>


<p style="font-size:150%;margin:20px;width:75%;margin-right:150px;">

  
   <i><font color = "#9b1313">



</p>


<p style="font-size:5vw;"></p>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""></a>  

</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">

      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

      </button>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="">&nbsp;<br></a> 

  <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> </a>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

          <li class="nav-item active">

            <a class="nav-link" href=""></a>

          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">



<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/index.html" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a> 

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">


              <a class="dropdown-item" href="guerillamarketing.html">Guerilla Marketing</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="patents.html">Patents</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="sumup.html">What's next ... ?</a>

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>


            </div>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="container">

  </div>

      <div class="starter-template">

      </div>



    </div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 


  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Replace those funky quotation marks `href=“/index.html”` around `/index.html`. Maybe not the cause but should be fixed.

Comment: do you have a link or sandbox? I'd like to use dev tools or something that'll give me some more details. It could be a few things. 1) if the icon is an image, the image could be lost (if referenced from an external source or similar logic), 2) z-index, 3) colors (transparent for instance?), 4) something else... Could be quite a few things tbh.

Comment: You have too many unclosed tags, a nav a li. A little tip try to re-write the code in a cleaner way.

Comment: Your code is also incomplete. Too many unclosed tags etc. Please incorporate the entire navbar in your sample code.

Comment: @Martin Placed complete page source in OP